# How to integrate an image (set via local path) in the exported HTML in emacs?

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I would like to export an HTML file that contains some images (added via local path) to appear outside my computer. How can I integrate/embed/burn the image in the file for public view?

I can successfully manage to do this on R Markdown but unable to pull it off on emacs as I have only started using it.

Here's what I typed:

```lisp
#+CAPTION: I-V curve for a diode
#+NAME:   fig:diode_1
#+attr_html: :width 250px
[[C:\Users\Documents\thres.png]]
```

I am hoping to get the local image exported into the final HTML document permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy this code into the *scratch* buffer and `C-M-x` it. Then export the .org file to html as usual.

```
(defun org-html--format-image (source attributes info)
  (format "<img src=\"data:image/%s;base64,%s\"%s />"
      (or (file-name-extension source) "")
      (base64-encode-string
       (with-temp-buffer
     (insert-file-contents-literally source)
     (buffer-string)))
      (file-name-nondirectory source)))
```

It puts the images directly into the html file thanks to base64 encoding.

Comment: Thanks @picaud-vincent for taking the time to write this. I did copy the above and replaced the source with my file paths and `C-M-x` it and it says `org-html--format-image`. However, when I exported the bespoke `org` file as HTML, the images still do not appear. I think I have not fully understood this and surely doing something incorrect. Do the images associated with the file need to be in the same folder as the `org` file by any chance?

Comment: @AJCMohan you are welcome. I have tested it and it worked for me. "it says org-html--format-image" <- that's good because Emacs must say that. IMHO you must check first your image org mode link. Under linux it's `[[file:~/Temp/image.png]]`, I have no experience with windows, but maybe try  `[[file:C:\...\image.png]]`.

Comment: @AJCMohan to test if your image link works (independently of the html export), if your click it, Emacs should open the image in another buffer. If not it means that the link is broken. Another more systematic way to control if your org mode file is well formed is to use do `M-x` and `org-lint`

Comment: Thank you @picaud-vincent. It seems to be working now. In this scuffle, I tried numerous other ways and one other way suggested by John Kitchin also worked as described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27060/embed-image-as-base64-on-html-export-from-orgmode). Since this is sorted I came across another problem. Is there a way to scale the image in `base64` format? The images are way too large in the exported HTML and the standard HTML attributes are not working for them.